# Query to multiply a data before .ToString

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi i have this code that i get a integer from database and .tostring

```
x.secTxnTime.ToString(),
```

let say the secTxnTime value is 5. before .tostring value 5 i want to multiply it by 60 how can it be done?

Comment: If you have an integer and you want to multiply it by 60, why don't you just multiply it by 60? And how in the world does your question have anything to do with [tag:model-view-controller]? It is not clear at all what you actually want help with here. Please see [ask]. Include a good [mcve] along with a precise description of what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do.

Comment: Great question.. i've never seen so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know its actual type is int and x.secTxnTime is object

```
((int)x.secTxnTime * 60).ToString()
```

Comment: Great answer... Never respond to very basic questions. Instead ask the questioner to do home work. No SPAM question/answers here. Thanks.